# Bounded Linear Operator + Surjective = Fried Egg

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is there an easy way to show for bounded linear operators that happen to be surjective:
 $\exists r\geq0: \overline{B_1(0)}\subseteq T(B_r(0))$
[image]
Thanks for hints!

Comment: You have to draw an yellow ball.

Comment: If the domain and range are Banach spaces this is the open mapping theorem.

Comment: Oh ^^ actually blue=cool and since open sets seem really cold and heartless to me I prefer painting them frosty ;)

Comment: Yes you got it, thats what I'm trying to prove ...so far I got: $ B_\epsilon\subseteq \overline{T(B_1)}\subseteq \lVert T\rVert B_2\stackrel{???}{\subseteq} T(B_r)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so far I got: $B_\epsilon \subseteq \overline{T(B_1)}$ ...

The usual proof goes on to show that then - supposing Banach spaces - you have $B_\epsilon \subseteq T(B_2)$ (for example, one can obtain a smaller radius).

By homogeneity, you have

$$B_{c\cdot \epsilon} \subseteq \overline{T(B_c)}$$

for all $c > 0$. Now let $y \in B_\epsilon$ arbitrary. Since $T(B_1)$ is dense in $B_\epsilon$, there is an $x_0 \in B_1$ with $\lVert y - T(x_0)\rVert < \epsilon/2$. Let $y_1 = y - T(x_0)$. Since $T(B_{1/2})$ is dense in $B_{\epsilon/2}$, there is an $x_1 \in B_{1/2}$ with $\lVert y_1 - T(x_1)\rVert < \epsilon/4$. Let $y_2 = y_1 - T(x_1) = y - \bigl(T(x_0) + T(x_1)\bigr)$. Since $T(B_{1/4})$ is dense in $B_{\epsilon/4}$, there is ... You get the gist.

Since $X$ - let us suppose the domain of $T$ is named thus - is complete,

$$\xi = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$$

exists, and $\lVert\xi\rVert \leqslant \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \lVert x_n\rVert < 2$. Show that $T(\xi) = y$.

Note that once you know that $T$ is open, you can deduce from $B_\epsilon \subseteq \overline{T(B_1)}$ that you actually have $B_\epsilon \subseteq T(B_1)$, since for every $\delta > 0$ the image $T(B_\delta)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$, whence

$$\overline{T(B_1)} \subseteq \bigcap_{\delta > 0}\left(T(B_1) + T(B_\delta)\right) = \bigcap_{\delta > 0} T(B_{1+\delta}),$$

so for every $\delta > 0$ you have $B_\epsilon \subseteq T(B_{1+\delta})$, which by homogeneity is equivalent to $B_{\epsilon/(1+\delta)}\subseteq T(B_1)$ for all $\delta > 0$, and hence

$$B_\epsilon = \bigcup_{\delta > 0}B_{\epsilon/(1+\delta)} \subseteq T(B_1).$$

Comment: Can you describe the idea of your proof in a few words?

Comment: The basic idea is to find a sequence $\xi_n$ of points in $B_2$ such that $T(\xi_n) \to y$, and $\xi_n \to \xi$. More detailed, you (roughly) halve the error in each step, and the step between consecutive $\xi_n$, so that you can guarantee both convergences.

Comment: Aaah, so you could as well change the speed of convergence separately as long as $B_{\epsilon b_n}\subseteq\overline{T(B_{\epsilon a_n})}$ as well as $\Sigma a_n<\infty$ and $b_n\to 0$ ...the proof seems *really* clever

Comment: Yes, there is no need to have both shrink at the same rate, it's just convenient to always halve the bounds.

Comment: Oh, it's not only convenient but you striclty have to require the same bound simultaneously for every point in the closure...

Comment: No, I could for example have $\lVert y_n - T(x_n)\rVert < \epsilon/4^n$, and $\lVert x_n\rVert < (2/3)^n$. With $B_\epsilon \subseteq \overline{T(B_1)}$, one cannot let the $x_n$ shrink at a faster rate than $y_n$, but slower is no problem.

Comment: Well, I meant that the bounds must be independant of the points $\lVert\Sigma x_n(y)\rVert\leq\Sigma a_n(y)=a(y)=const$

Comment: Ah, yes, you need the same bounds on the $x_n$ for all $y$. Well, you need a global bound on the sum, $a(y) \leqslant C$ for all $y$.

Comment: So what we did show is: $B_\epsilon\subseteq\overline{T(B_1)}\Rightarrow B_\epsilon\subseteq T(B_{1+\delta})$ ...I was expecting that even: $B_\epsilon\subseteq\overline{T(B_1)}\Rightarrow B_\epsilon\subseteq T(B_1)$ Is there a counterexample on that?

Comment: No, there is no counterexample. As I showed in the last part, once you know that $T$ is open, you can deduce $B_\epsilon \subseteq \overline{T(B_1)} \Rightarrow B_\epsilon \subseteq T(B_1)$. But as an intermediate step, $B_\varepsilon \subseteq T(B_{1+\delta})$ may be necessary. It's certainly convenient.

Comment: but you have to rescale the epsilon

Comment: But since we have $B_{\epsilon/(1+\delta)} \subseteq T(B_1)$ for all $\delta > 0$, the union is also contained in $T(B_1)$. And the union is $B_\epsilon$ itself.

Comment: Ah right *d'ooh* ^^

Answer (score 0):

I just remember a theorem which says:

If $g:E\to F$ is a homeomorphism such that $g^{-1}$ is lipschitz with $Lipg^{-1}<\lambda$ then $\overline{B_{\dfrac{r}{\lambda}}}(g(x))\subset g(\overline{B_r}(x))$. But i am not sure whether this can help you or not.

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't help since the operator not necessarily needs to be a homeomorphism until the open mapping theorem proves that the continuity of the inverse actually comes for free.

Comment: what about this one: $f :\mathbb{R}^m\to  \mathbb{R}^m$ is a continuous map such that $\vert f (x) − f (y)\vert \geq a\vert x − y\vert$ for some a > 1, for all x, y  $R^m$. If $f (0) = 0$, then the image of a ball of radius $r > 0$ centered at 0 contains the ball of radius $ar$ centered at $0$.

Comment: The inverse of a function with that property no matter the size of $a$ is, well, lipschitz so also continuous. But the point is: Can you deduce the continuity of the inverse without any additional assumption? In fact, the open mapping theorem says yes you can - no supplementary requirements needed ;)